# A linear map on $V^{\ast} \times V \times V \to \mathbb R$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $V$ is a real vector space and $T: V^{\ast} \times V \times \ldots \times V \to \mathbb R$(n copies intotal) is $n-$linear. Then $T$ can be thought of as an $n-1$ linear map from $V \times \ldots \times V \to \mathbb V$, why should this be true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given such a map $T$, you can consider the map $S : V^{n-1}\to V^{**}$ such that $$S(v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1})(f) = T(f,v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1})$$ where $f\in V^*$. This is usually known as the hom-tensor adjunction: bilinear maps $f : U\times V\to W$ stand in bijection with linear maps $g:U\to \hom(V,W)$ by means of 
$$g(u)(v) = f(u,v).$$
If $V$ is finite dimensional you can identify $V^{**}$ with $V$ canonically, thus obtaining the desired map.